# Content routing SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, routes, sapui5

I want to routing to page in SAPUI5 but not all page. So, I want routing just for content, exclude header (dropdown menu) in picture. How to route separated page?

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OzEL.png)

Thanks all.
Bobby

Answer (score 0):

**XML code inside content**

```
                <App id="navCon">
                    <pages>
                        <Page id="contentOne" showHeader="false">
                            <Text text="page 1 content"/>
                            <Button text="Next Content" press="nextContent"></Button>
                        </Page>
                        <Page id="contentTwo" showHeader="false">
                            <Text text="page 2 content"/>
                                <Button text="Previous Content" press="prevContent"></Button>
                        </Page>
                    </pages>
                </App>
```

**Controller code**

```
    onInit : function(){
            this.navCon = this.getView().byId("navCon");    
    },
    nextContent : function(){
        this.navCon.to(this.getView().byId("contentTwo"), "slide");
    },

    prevContent : function(){
        this.navCon.to(this.getView().byId("contentOne"), "slide");
    }
```

> Place the code according to your needs and the functionality is the same.